# The type of a local declared in a fixed statement must be a pointer type

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fix the bellow code compiler giving error:
**The type of a local declared in a fixed statement must be a pointer type.**

anyone can tell me what's wrong here

```
       sbyte[] array = (sbyte[])(Array)Encoding.Default.GetBytes("MyAESCtr"); ;

        fixed (sbyte[] array4 = array)
        {
            sbyte* algo;
            if (array != null && array4.Length != 0)
            {
                algo = &array4[0];
            }
            else
            {
                algo = null;
            }
        }
```

here is the function I send values to :

```
 public unsafe int Encrypt(sbyte* Algo, sbyte* szd, sbyte* ped)
 internal unsafe static extern int EncryptC(sbyte*, sbyte*, _UString*, sbyte*);
```

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: as a side note: you should avoid `Encoding.Default` like the plague; what encoding did you actually mean there? use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `fixed` like this, the new variable is the *pointer*, i.e.

```cs
fixed (sbyte* array4 = array)
```

However! I don't think you need `unsafe` code here, and you probably *shouldn't* be pinning here. Just... use it as an array! There needs to be a very good reason to use `fixed`/`unsafe`, and I just don't see *any* reason here. If you just want the value:

```cs
var algo = array[0];
```

If you really need a pointer, prefer a *managed* pointer:

```cs
ref sbyte algo = ref array[0];
```

---

edit; from comments, it seems that there is some P/Invoke going on here; that *is* a valid scenario for `fixed`, in which case this should work fine:

```cs
fixed (sbyte* ptr = array)
{
    sbyte* algo = null;
    if (array != null && array.Length != 0)
    {
        algo = ptr; // &ptr[0] **is** ptr
    }
    YourUnmanagedMethod(algo);
}
```

Important: you *must not* use the pointer once you've left the `fixed` scope; the pointer is *unreliable* after that point due to how the GC works.

Comment: @OGMomo k; passing it to C++ *is* a good a relevant reason to use `fixed` - that is necessary context, thanks; however, you need to talk to C++ **inside** the `fixed` block (the pointer is unreliable outside of that time); I'll add an edit - it should work fine